# Extract subset of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, subset

I know how to extract a subset from a normal vector and how to extract a subset from a vector that is inside another vector. My question is now how I can extract subsets of all vectors that are inside another vector.

For example: I have three vectors inside another one:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec;
std::vector<int> vec_1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec_2{11,12,13,14,15};
std::vector<int> vec_3{21,22,23,24,25};

my_vec.push_back(vec_1);
my_vec.push_back(vec_2);
my_vec.push_back(vec_3);
```

What I want to do now is create a new vector which contains the subset of the third and fourth element of each vector.
I tried this:

```
#include<vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec;
std::vector<int> vec_1{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> vec_2{11,12,13,14,15};
std::vector<int> vec_3{21,22,23,24,25};

my_vec.push_back(vec_1);
my_vec.push_back(vec_2);
my_vec.push_back(vec_3);

// For a normal vector
std::vector<int> vec_1_subset(vec_1.begin()+2,vec_1.begin()+4);

for (auto& element: vec_1_subset)
{
std::cout<<element<<std::endl;
}

// For extracting from a single vector inside another vector
std::vector<int> my_vec_subset((my_vec[0]).begin()+2,(my_vec[0]).begin()+4);

for (auto& element: my_vec_subset)
{
std::cout<<element<<std::endl;
}

// For several vectors inside a vector ?
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec_test_subset(my_vec.begin()+2,my_vec.begin()+4);

return 0;
}
```

The last try creates an error message.

Comment: `my_vec` is a vector of vector of int and `my_vec_test_subset` is a vector of int. You're trying to copy 2 vectors into a vector of int which doesn't make any sense and hence the error.

Comment: you are right about this. I already fixed it in the code. It was a mistake during the creating of the sample code. I still do no understand how I can extract the third and fourth elements of each vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> res;
res.reserve(my_vec.size());

std::transform(my_vec.begin(), my_vec.end(),
               std::back_inserter(res),
               [](const std::vector<int>& v){ return std::vector<int>{v.begin() + 2,
                                                                      v.begin() + 4}; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow up from my latest comment:

If I understand your question correctly, then one possible way to do it is given below:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec;
    std::vector<int> vec_1{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> vec_2{11,12,13,14,15};
    std::vector<int> vec_3{21,22,23,24,25};
    my_vec.push_back(vec_1);
    my_vec.push_back(vec_2);
    my_vec.push_back(vec_3);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vec_test_subset;
    for(const auto vec:my_vec)
        my_vec_test_subset.push_back({vec.begin()+2,vec.begin()+4});
    for(const auto vec:my_vec_test_subset){
        for(const auto i:vec)
            std::cout<<i<<" ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
3 4 
13 14 
23 24
```

Comment: you should use /*const*/ auto& in loops to avoid unnecessary copies. Also, your code will crash if the array has less than 4 items.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I'm avoiding length checks because the author said he/she always wants to retrieve the 3rd and 4th elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto GetVectorSubset(const vector<vector<int>>& source)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(source.size()*2);

    for (const auto &vec: source)
    {
        try
        {
            result.emplace_back(vec.at(2));
            result.emplace_back(vec.at(3));
        }
        catch(std::exception&) {};
    }

    return result;
}
```

This example might not be the most optimal, but it's nice and gets the job done. It relies on the fact thet the vector::at() method will throw an exception if you go out-of-bound.

If the exception is too ugly for you, you'll need to test the size of the vector 2 times:

```
if (vec.size() > 2) result.emplace_back(vec[2]);
if (vec.size() > 3) result.emplace_back(vec[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

my_vec_test_subset(my_vec.begin()+2,my_vec.begin()+4);
type will be std::vector> not std::vector
and also my_vec has only three (not four) element and will throw exception if you fix the type

if you want a std::vector that include array of element 3 and4 of N vectors below code is what you need

```
    std::vector<int> finalV;
for (auto& element : my_vec) {
    finalV.insert(finalV.end(), element.begin()+2, element.begin()+4);
}
```

and if you want a vector vectors witch contains 3th,and4th elements of elements of my_vec here's the code you need

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> finalV2;
for (auto& element : my_vec) {
    finalV2.push_back(std::vector<int>(element.begin() + 2, element.begin() + 4));
}
```